# Подсчет количество подряд значений

Tags: python

имеется xlsx файл, в котором имеются 2 столбца

Необходимо определить сколько раз подряд разность между двумя столбцами была положительна, отрицательна или 0
Например:

```
23 3   понижение
10 19  возрастание
10 11  возрастание
12 14  возрастание
1 0    понижение
234 123 понижение
0 1    возрастание
0 0    равно
```

Результат:

```
1 - 1 понижение, 1 возрастание, 1 - равно
2 - 1 понижение
3 - 1 возрастание
```

Код

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy
import time
count_ups = 0
count_downs = 0
count_zero = 0
start_time = time.time()
data = pd.read_excel("2.xlsx")
rows = data.values
dict_ups = {}
dict_zero = {}
dict_downs = {}
for row in rows:
    if(row[0] - row[1]>0):
        if(count_ups != 0):
            dict_ups[count_ups] = dict_ups.get(count_ups, 0) + 1
        else:
            if(count_zero != 0):
                dict_zero[count_zero] = dict_zero.get(count_zero, 0) + 1
        count_downs += 1
        count_zero = 0
        count_ups = 0
    else:
        if(row[0] - row[1] < 0 ):
            if (count_downs != 0):
                dict_downs[count_downs] = dict_downs.get(count_downs, 0) +1
            else:
                if (count_zero != 0):
                    dict_zero[count_zero] = dict_zero.get(count_zero, 0) + 1
            count_ups += 1
            count_zero = 0
            count_downs = 0
        else:
            if (count_downs != 0):
                dict_downs[count_downs] = dict_downs.get(count_downs, 0) + 1
            else:
                if (count_ups != 0):
                    dict_ups[count_ups] = dict_ups.get(count_ups, 0) + 1
            count_zero += 1
            count_ups = 0
            count_downs = 0

print(time.time() - start_time)
print(dict_zero)
print(dict_downs)
print(dict_ups)
```

В чем ошибка данного решения? Не находит положительные. Посоветуйте, как можно увеличить **производительность** расчета. 
И как отсортировать словарь по key в порядке возрастания?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что в результате получается. Можете объяснить?

Comment: Кажется понял, имеются в виду общие кол-ва понижений, возрастаний и равно подряд во всем списке без учета их следования. Сначала идёт 1 понижение, затем 3 возрастания, затем 2 понижения, 1 возрастание и 1 равно. В итоге получается: `1 - понижение, возрастание, равно`; `2 - понижение`; `3 - возрастание`. Например, если бы после равно шло 5 возрастаний подряд, а затем 3 понижения, то бы в результат добавилось ещё `5 - возрастание`, а `3 - возрастание` изменилось бы на `3 - возрастание, понижение`.

Comment: Можете выложить пример Excel файла на какой-нибудь файлообменник?

Comment: @MaxU https://yadi.sk/i/l1hn_z9ZIVuQ6g

Answer (score 1):

Можно решить отталкиваясь от этого алгоритма:

```python
from itertools import groupby
from collections import defaultdict

# хотя лучше уже подавать разность на вход
def is_positive_negative_or_zero(n):
    if n[1] - n[0] > 0: return 1
    if n[1] - n[0] < 0: return -1
    return 0

d = defaultdict(list)

for k, g in groupby(rows, key=is_positive_negative_or_zero):
    d[len(list(g))].append(k)

print(d)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: [-1, 1, 0], 2: [-1], 3: [1]})
# где -1 - понижение, 0 - равно, 1 - возрастание
```